# Ubuntu 18.04 login screen looks weird

Tags: login, lock-screen

It asks for login profile name and then password. Is it some kind of problem or it looks that way?

[image: picture of login screen]

Answer (score 8):

Check your installation log under `/var/log/apt/history.log`. You will probably find that you (perhaps by accident) installed a package called "xdm". Simply removing the xdm package using this command

```
sudo apt remove xdm
```

should switch back to which ever login manager you were using before. As an alternative to uninstalling xdm you could use the following command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

to make ubuntu use the default login manager again.