# My Login Screen is different Help!

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 this day. Everything is fine until my screen froze and did not come back. So I restarted my computer and when it booted, my Login screen was different. Sadly I couldn't make a screenshot of it. But I can describe how it looks, so I hope this can help. It has a rectangular box in the middle. It says "Welcome to ", it has a login form for my username and password and it has an Ubuntu logo on the side.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. when you installed Ubuntu 18.04, did you get a message like "Ubuntu is successfully Installed, Restart your Computer"?? and your login screen is different in the first attempt? or you successfully logged on with your credentials in the previous?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has a different login screen than previous versions of Ubuntu. Can you log in fine? Is it a problem for you to continue with this new login screen?

Comment: This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045463/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-looks-weird?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those who answered and sorry for the trouble. I actually found out the answer to my problem. It turns out that I actually installed XDM which replaced GDM thinking that this XDM is the download manager. I fixed my problem by switching back to GDM. Again Sorry for the trouble and thank you for those who answered