# Ubuntu login broken

Tags: 18.04, login, login-screen

I have recently downloaded ubuntu dual boot with windows 10 on my laptop. It was working fine until I shutdown my laptop and restarted it.

I got an old ubuntu login page [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YImqS.jpg) and even if a login I get stuck with a page with only the background [(picture after login)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFPu.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: This may be related (at least to the first part of your question): [Ubuntu 18.04 login screen looks weird](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045463/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-looks-weird)

Comment: Please advise if you validated the download before creating your LiveUSB or LiveDVD following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview